# Inheritance in Java - "Cannot find symbol constructor"

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm working on a class that inherits from another class, but I'm getting a compiler error saying "Cannot find symbol constructor Account()". Basically what I'm trying to do is make a class InvestmentAccount which extends from Account - Account is meant to hold a balance with methods for withdrawing/depositing money and InvestmentAccount is similar, but the balance is stored in shares with a share price determining how many shares are deposited or withdrawn given a particular amount of money. Here's the first few lines (around where the compiler pointed out the problem) of the subclass InvestmentAccount:

```
public class InvestmentAccount extends Account
{
    protected int sharePrice;
    protected int numShares;
    private Person customer;

    public InvestmentAccount(Person customer, int sharePrice)
    {
        this.customer = customer;
        sharePrice = sharePrice;
    }
    // etc...
```

The Person class is held in another file (Person.java). Now here's the first few lines of the superclass Account:

```
public class Account 
{
    private Person customer;
    protected int balanceInPence;

    public Account(Person customer)
    {
        this.customer = customer;
        balanceInPence = 0;
    }
    // etc...
```

Is there any reason why the compiler isn't just reading the symbol constructor for Account from the Account class? Or do I need to define a new constructor for Account within InvestmentAccount, which tells it to inherit everything?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use `super(customer)` in `InvestmentAccount`s constructor.

Java can not know how to call the **only** constructor `Account` has, because it's not an *empty constructor*. You can omit `super()` only if your base class has an empty constuctor.

Change

```
public InvestmentAccount(Person customer, int sharePrice)
{
        this.customer = customer;
        sharePrice = sharePrice;
}
```

to

```
public InvestmentAccount(Person customer, int sharePrice)
{
        super(customer);
        sharePrice = sharePrice;
}
```

that will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to invoke the superclass constructor, otherwise Java won't know what constructor you are calling to build the superclass on the subclass.

```
public class InvestmentAccount extends Account {
    protected int sharePrice;
    protected int numShares;
    private Person customer;

    public InvestmentAccount(Person customer, int sharePrice) {
        super(customer);
        this.customer = customer;
        sharePrice = sharePrice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the constructor of the base class explicitly if the base class doesn't have a default constructor (one with no arguments).

In your case, the constructor should be:

```
public InvestmentAccount(Person customer, int sharePrice) {
    super(customer);
    sharePrice = sharePrice;
}
```

And don't redefine `customer` as an instance variable of the subclass!

Answer (score 1):

Call the super() method. If you want to call the Account(Person) constructor, use the statement super(customer); Also this should be the first statment in your InvestmentAccount 
constructor

Comment: Not “should be” but “has to”.

Answer (score 1):

Either define a default constructor in the `Account` class:

```
public Account() {}
```

Or call `super(customer)` in the `InvestmentAccount` constructor.